# How to prevent transparent borders (collars) of a tif wipe out overlapping regions of adjecent tif while using gdalbuildvrt

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, transparency-opacity, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

I have a set of Geotifs that have got transparent borders (collars) of irregular shapes & dimensions around them. First I created a VRT over this set of Geotifs through gdalbuildvrt. Then I generated tiles through gdal2tiles.py using this VRT.

I noticed that the transparent borders (collars) of some Geotifs wiped out the overlapping regions of the adjacent Geotifs creating holes in the output.

Is there any setting that I should use while creating VRT through gdalbuildvrt or while generating tiles through gdal2tiles.py and the above created VRT, so that I can get rid of the holes in the output caused by the transparent borders (collars) of some Geotifs wiping out the overlapping regions of adjacent Geotifs.

Comment: Try -srcnodata in gdalbuildvrt if input files have a common nodata value. Gdalinfo should report that.